# How do I send and receive an string array from client to server in Java socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, http, client-server

// Heres the client part of the client-side. I Don't know why my server isn't receiving the data, is feeding through an array the wrong way to do it and if so is there any other solutions I could look at?

```
System.out.println("Trying to Connect to Server");
            // connect to server and extract input and output streams
            try (Socket serverSocket = new Socket(hostName, hostPort);
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream()));
                    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverSocket.getInputStream()))) {

            // create client input stream for user input
            Scanner scanners = new Scanner(System.in); //create scanner object
            System.out.println("Enter the number sequence you wish to be checked");
            String sarray = scanners.nextLine();
            numbers = sarray.split(" ");
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
            int size = numbers.length;
            int[] arr = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
            }

            // send the values to the server
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                os.write(numbers[i].getBytes());
                os.flush();
            }


            // read message back from server
            System.out.println(is.readLine());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception:  " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

// Heres part of the server-side. The client accepts a variable-length sequence of integer values from the user and submits them to the server for processing. The server finds the largest consecutive subsequence and returns to the client the length of this subsequence followed by the subsequence. The client then displays to the user the length of the subsequence followed by the subsequence.

```
//accept client connection
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                try (DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                        PrintWriter os = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())))) {
                    System.out.println("Client Accepted");
                    //read array numbers from client
                    String[] numbers = is.toString().split(" ");
                    // decide the response
                    int size = numbers.length;
                    int[] arr = new int[size];
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
                    }
                    int n = arr.length;
                    HashSet<Integer> a = new HashSet<>();
                    int ans = 0;
                    // Hash all the array elements
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                        a.add(arr[i]);
                    }
                    // check each possible sequence from the start
                    // then update optimal length
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                        // if current element is the starting
                        // element of a sequence
                        if (!a.contains(arr[i] - 1)) {
                            // Then check for next elements in the
                            // sequence
                            int j = arr[i];
                            while (a.contains(j)) {
                                j++;
                            }
                            // update optimal length if this length
                            // is more
                            if (ans < j - arr[i]) {
                                ans = j - arr[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(a.toString());
                    System.out.println("Length of longest Consecutive Sequence = " + ans);
                    os.println(ans);
                    os.flush();
                    System.out.println("Session Over");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IOException:" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }//end while
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }//end main
}
```

// Expected output would be: 
If you input for example the following six numbers:
5  2  12  4 3  9 
You will get back:
Length of longest Consecutive Sequence = 4
Longest Consecutive Sequence values are: [2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: As far as I see from input `5 2 12 4 3 9` , output can be obtained only is input is sorted previous. `(out: 2, 3, 4, 5)`:`sorted(2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 12)`. Basically your first issues is with algorithm not with transmission ...

Comment: @TraianGEICU yea I thought the algorithm was off but I was going to fix it after the server was receiving the date. Feeding data from client to the server is what I am wanting to achieve and then I'll deal with the actual algorithm after.

Comment: `os.write(numbers[i].getBytes())` -> send array elements one by one and not full array, so when receive you get the same:  one element follow by other (till stop maybe -1). When stop then start to process. ` String[] numbers = is.toString().split(" ");` : do not match with what is sent.Need something `int number = is.readInt()` ...